# Effect of time.sleep on thread access

Tags: python, multithreading, sleep, thread-sleep

In python, I have a multi-threading application that accesses a global object. Am curious, if I put time.sleep() on a thread (say THREAD 1) that is about to access the global object, does time.sleep() delay THREAD 1's access to the global object such that other threads that don't have time.sleep() are able to get access first to the global object?

Comment: From what I understand, if you put sleep on thread-1 before accessing global object, then other threads who don't have sleep will get access first. What exactly are you trying to ask here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Threads are pretty complicated in Python and operate in the same memory heap. The threads basically run concurrently, i.e. multiple threads are interleaved together such that only on runs at a time and they together run alternatively in very short spans of time (considering they need access to the interpreter).

When you put a thread to sleep, it basically uses the underlying system sleep features and blocks all operations on it. However, the other threads are definitely operational. Thus, when you say THREAD1 is put on sleep before it was just about to access a global variable, the other threads will obviously use the variable because they are running while THREAD1 is not.

As soon as THREAD1 wakes up, if need be, it shall acquire the GIL and thus access the global variable. Since it again gets interleaved with other threads, due to concurrency, it gets immediate access to the global variable upon activation. If other threads were using it, they would have given up their access before THREAD1 started operations.